# Filling array with data from one specified MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, field

The field:
Friends, and contains something like "2,3,6,3,67,97"
the numbers are user ID's.

i want to know if there is a way to get those numbers into an array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is wrong with http://php.net/explode ?

Comment: As a side note: Having a field like this is a bad idea in 99% of all cases. Look into database normalization and create a table like CREATE TABLE friended_user ( user_id INT, friended_user_id INT) and do some JOINs

Answer (score 2):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/explode) method

```
$data = "2,3,6,3,67,97";
$dataarray= explode(",",$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
$counter = 0;
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $array[$counter] = explode(",", $row['friends']) // or whatever the column is called
    $counter++;
}
```

So for the first entry in the database,

```
$array[0][0] = 2
$array[0][1] = 3 // etc etc...
```

Apologies if the code is wrong, been a while since I've worked with multi-dimensional arrays. Hope the concepts helped though :)